# Why in Scala function defined without empty parentheses doesn't behave like function?

Tags: scala, parentheses

Consider the following 2 objects

```
object TestObj1 {
  def testMethod = "Some text"
}

object TestObj2 {
  def testMethod() = "Some text"
}
```

and if I call those methods directly, they do what I expect

```
scala> TestObj1.testMethod
res1: String = Some text

scala> TestObj2.testMethod
res2: String = Some text
```

But now if we define following function

```
def functionTakingFunction(callback: () => String) {
  println("Call returns: " + callback())
}
```

and try to call it, the method defined without () is not accepted.

```
scala> functionTakingFunction(TestObj1.testMethod)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: () => String
              functionTakingFunction(TestObj1.testMethod)
                                              ^

scala> functionTakingFunction(TestObj2.testMethod)
Call returns: Some text
```

I also noticed that you can't call the TestObj1.testMethod using parentheses, since it already is a String. But what is causing this behavior?

Comment: Just to point out, @om-nom-nom answer is right (it gets things done), still, the reason for the type mismatch is that `def foo` and `def foo()` are two different mammals in Scala... While they are both **0-arity** methods, empty argument list and no argument list wilds different results, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409502/what-is-the-difference-between-def-foo-and-def-foo-in-scala.

Comment: Those aren't functions, they are methods.

Comment: @JörgWMittag my bad on the naming. But would it make a difference if they were functions? And the functionTakingFunctiondoesn't know are you passing a function or a method, right?

Comment: Yes, it would make a difference. Functions are objects, methods aren't. You *cannot* pass a method to a method, precisely because it *isn't* an object. You can only pass functions to methods. If you want to do anything with a method, you have to η-expand it using `_`. Scala will *sometimes* perform *implicit η-expansion*, *if* it can clearly see that you do *not* actually want to call the method but convert it to a function and pass it as an argument. But in your first example it can *not* clearly see that, because that's a legal method call.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly post you linked shares quite a bit of clarity on what is happening in the background, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not passing the method, you're invoking it and then passing its result into the call.

If you want to pass the method, you first have to convert it into a function, and pass that:

```
functionTakingFunction(TestObj1.testMethod _)
```

Here the `testMethod` is converted into a **partially applied** function (said to be "tied").

The reason you have to do that is because `TestObj1.testMethod` does not evaluate to `function0` (which is what need to be passed to `functionTakingFunction`), but to a `String` because of the way it is declared (without parentheses).

It works on `TestObj2` because the testMethod is defined with parentheses and thus just typing `TestObj2.testMethod` does not invoke it.

Comment: `testFunction` is not a `Function`, it is a method. Partial application when used with methods yields `FunctionN` (where N is the number of arguments to the method from which it was derived). It doesn't help understanding to blur the distinction between non-first-class entities (methods) and first-class function values.

Comment: @RandallSchulz quite fair, can you write your own answer, please? (I will remove mine then)

Comment: @Randall. `TestObj1.testFunction2` is also evaluated as `function0`, to all practical needs, the problem here is that `testFunction` is  evaluated as a String, so, despite the fact that `testFunction` and `testFunction2` are really methods, om-nom-nom solution is right ([Working Example](http://ideone.com/Hwo1Bq))

Comment: This solves the issue, it provides explanation and hints the right terms to search for more info, so thank you from the great answer.

Comment: I didn't say his code did not do what's intended, I just think people should understand what's what and what's really happening with that code.

Answer (score 0):

`functionTakingFunction(TestObj1.testFunction)` is called as `functionTakingFunction("Some text")` - it is evaluated rather than passed

Answer (score -1):

Here, you are not passing the function. What you are trying to do is evaluate `TestObj1.testFunction` and then pass that result to `functionTakingFunction`
But if you see the definition of functionTakingFunction, it says clearly

```
def functionTakingFunction(callback: () => String)
```

means this function expects a function with Return Type as Unit. But `TestObj1.testFunction` is having no return type.

The difference between Unit Return Type and No Return Type is:

- No Return Type means this method will not return anything
- Unit Return Type means this method will return something which is having no meaningful value.

Hope it helps you now. Happy coding and enjoy Scala.

Comment: This answer confuses me on so many levels. First is there actually a case in Scala where I would not get a return at all (meaning not even Unit). And second doesn't the "=> String" exactly mean that it expects function with return type as String.

Comment: "means this function expects a function with Return Type as Unit." – No, it means it expects a function with return type `String`. "`TestObj1.testFunction` is having no return type." – Wrong, it has return type `String`. There is no such thing as "no return type" in Scala. Everything has a return type. Everything *must* have a return type, since everything is an expression and thus everything returns *something*.