# Scala Action method in Play 2

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am pretty new to Scala and I am learning Play as well. I see the following construct used in Play

```
def list = Action {
    val products = Product.findAll
    Ok(views.html.products.list(products))
}
```

I am confused as to what

```
Action {}
```

does. Is `Action` the returned value of the method? What is this construct called if I want to know more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction called [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) enhanced via [scala apply sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737352/what-is-the-apply-function-in-scala)

`Action` in this reference is the [companion object](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html), which [could be called singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), but in fact along with very specific singleton type `Action$` it methods reflected as static methods of `Action`.

As we can read [`object Action extends ActionBuilder[Request]`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/d7432a4e41cec72e8b488116b71263329d3be9e2/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L489) which have [plenty of apply methods](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/d7432a4e41cec72e8b488116b71263329d3be9e2/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L381) constructing values of `Action` type.

Curly braces here presents [nullary function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670356/scala-passing-function-as-block-of-code-between-curly-braces) which is null-parameter [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))  and often named so in different languages like ruby or groovy. It's just multiline block of code which produces something at the end.