# Anonymous function as argument in scala

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

In Play 2.3, the `Action.async` method has the signature

```
final def async(block: ⇒ Future[Result]): Action[AnyContent]
```

I did not figure out the meaning of `=> Future[Result]`, is it an anonymous function? Then shouldn't it be `() => Future[Result]`?

Comment: You can find your  answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670356/scala-passing-function-as-block-of-code-between-curly-braces and in many other similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a "By-name parameter":

- [Call by name vs call by value in Scala, clarification needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337338/call-by-name-vs-call-by-value-in-scala-clarification-needed)
- [By-name parameter vs anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948598/by-name-parameter-vs-anonymous-function)

Answer (score 0):

This is a call by name not by value as usual. It means, the argument, here block is of Type Future[Result] and it is lazy evaluated when needed not instantly on function call.

Comment: it's a subtler difference than "lazily evaulated" - http://stackoverflow.com/q/13337338/409976.