# Executing code in bracket with function?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a wrapper function for `system.scheduler.schedule`. I started by writing the following code:

```
def every(time : Int) : Unit = {

    val system = ActorSystem("timer")
    import system.dispatcher
    val tickActor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[TickActor], this))

    system.scheduler.schedule(0 milliseconds, time.milliseconds, tickActor, Tick)
}
```

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
timer.every(10) {
    println("HI")
}
```

However, I'm getting: **Unit does not take parameters**

I don't think I've set my function call up correctly to accept the { }, but I don't know how. I don't even know the terminology so I can look it up... I'm really knew to scala.

What do they call something like this and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: you can write something like `def every(time:Int)(thunk: => Unit){...}` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670356/scala-passing-function-as-block-of-code-between-curly-braces

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.

Comment: From Martin Odersky, Programming in Scala, 2nd Edtition : ``` In any method invocation in Scala in which you’re passing in exactly one argument, you can opt to use curly braces to surround the argument instead of parentheses.``` Chapter 9, Control Abstraction, p 216