# What does the following warning mean: 'side-effecting nullary methods are discouraged'?

Tags: function, scala, parameters, intellij-idea

I have a lot of nullary methods (methods with 0 parameters) in my scala test file. Hence, instead of writing them as :

```
def fooBar() = //
```

I write them as :

```
def fooBar = //
```

I get the following warning when I do so:

```
Warning:(22, 7) side-effecting nullary methods are discouraged: suggest defining as `def fooBar()` instead
```

What is the meaning of the warning? I am using intelliJ as my IDE and could not really find much about this warning on the web.

**EDIT**

And, I forgot to mention, when I use the brackets, the warning does not appear.

Comment: Version of scala? Actual return type of `foobar`?

Comment: scala version is 2.10.2. Return type is Unit (They are test functions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The common *convention* for nullary methods is to:

- in case it's a side-effecting method, signify it with use of parenthesis
- otherwise, drop parenthesis in case it's pure accessor-like method with no side effects

You're breaking this rule and IDE warns you about this.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7606214/298389

Answer (score 3):

Does `fooBar` have side-effects?

It's simply stating a good practice to define a side-effecting method as such:

```
def fooBar() = ...
```

And non-side-effecting methods like this:

```
def fooBar = ...
```

Since the method call looks similar to accessing a `val`, it's good to differentiate when the method is doing more than just returning a value.