# Function call, where are parentheses

Tags: scala

I have following code snippet:

```
def now = System.currentTimeMillis
```

When I want to invoke the now function in REPL, just

```
now
```

why not

```
now()
```

and shows the error

```
<console>:9: error: Long does not take parameters
              now( )
```

Comment: try adding parens to your definition

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between def foo = {} and def foo() = {} in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409502/what-is-the-difference-between-def-foo-and-def-foo-in-scala)