# Close Connection for Mongodb using Casbah API

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I am not getting any useful information about "how to close connection for mongodb using casbah API". Actually, I have defined multiple methods and in each method I need to establish a connection with mongodb. After working I need to close that too. I am using Scala.

one of the method like (code example in scala):

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoConnection

def index ={
  val mongoConn = MongoConnection(configuration("hostname"))
  val log = mongoConn("ab")("log")
  val cursor = log.find()
  val data = for {x <- cursor} yield x.getAs[BasicDBObject]("message").get
  html.index(data.toList)
  //mongoConn.close()  <-- here i want to close the connection but this .close() is not working
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear, from your question why exactly close is not working. Does it throw some exception, it is not compiling, or has no effect?
But since `MongoConnection` is a thin wrapper over `com.mongodb.Mongo`, you could work with underlying Mongo directly, just like in plain old Java driver:

```
val mongoConn = MongoConnection(configuration("hostname"))
mongoConn.underlying.close()
```

Actually, that's exactly, how close [is implemented](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-core/src/main/scala/MongoConnection.scala#L225) in casbah.

Comment: thanks , its working.(I am new here so i cant vote up [:(] ).

Answer (score 0):

Try using .close instead.  If a function doesn't have arguments in scala, you [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939908/scala-functions-with-no-arguments) don't use parentheses after it.

EDIT: I had wrong information, edited to include correct information + link.

Comment: Actually, it is better to use parentheses sometimes - e.g. if function you're calling has side effects (and `.close()` here is definitely has them).

Comment: my question is *how exactly it is not working?*, e.g. what is the problem?

Comment: hmm, indeed, trying it in my local console it works out fine.